# QTP 11 crashes on Windows 7 (error with XmlIfsComWrap.dll)

Tags: qtp

I am recently using QTP 11 on Windows 7, after the original installation, QTP start successfully, but some menu items were lost, so I re-install it, but this time, I even cannot launch it, it crash immediately when I launch it. see pictures below.

[image]

After checking the event log, I found the following information

```
Faulting application name: QTPro.exe, version: 11.0.1018.0, time stamp: 0x4c568649
Faulting module name: XmlIfsComWrap.dll, version: 11.0.1018.0, time stamp: 0x4c56c920
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00005144
Faulting process id: 0xb94
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceb9c19858b796
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\QuickTest Professional\bin\QTPro.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\QuickTest Professional\bin\XmlIfsComWrap.dll
Report Id: dcf26456-25b4-11e3-ab4b-f01faf2a255e
```

It seems there is something wrong with XmlIfsComWrap.dll, after googling for a while, I didn't get anything helpful, any idea?

Comment: Did you do a clean re-install, i.e. deinstall, remove file and registry orphans, and re-install with an admin user? Does this then happen to the same user that re-installed? I bet not.

Comment: Yes, this happen to the same user with admin. Uninstall in control panel. I will try clean registry orphans. thanks.

Comment: Do you have Sprinter installed on the same machine?

Comment: For colliding with the DLL you mentioned :) no its a rather new manual testing support tool from HP